# C# Indexof return value -1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I am trying to get the index value of one particular item from one list. But the function returned value -1. May I know what's the reason of indexof return -1?

Comment: This can happen if the item is not in the list.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17(v=vs.110).aspx)?  Specifically the part where it says: "[Returns] The zero-based index of the first occurrence of item within the entire List<T>, if found; **otherwise, –1.**"

Comment: The item suppose to be getting the index is in the list

Comment: @NgZen **or -1 if the item is not in the list**

Comment: @maccettura you might want to post that as an answer

Answer (score 1):

The reason `IndexOf()` is returning `-1` is because the item you are trying to find **does not exist in the list**.

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17(v=vs.110).aspx), `IndexOf` will return "the zero-based index of the first occurrence of item within the entire List, if found; otherwise, –1.".

You should step through with the debugger, you will find that the item you are trying to find the index of **is not in your list**.

Keep in mind (and again, this is in the documentation). That "this method determines equality using the default equality comparer EqualityComparer.Default for T, the type of values in the list.".  So if you are convinced that your item *should* be in the list, you should look at the EqualityComparer for your type.

Comment: I did a foreach loop to check if this item is exist. It does exist in the list

Comment: @NgZen read my last paragraph.  Just because you see it in the list in the debugger, does not mean that the EqualityComparer for your type finds them to be equal.

Comment: Ok I will check the equality by using Equals function. Thanks

Comment: End up the reason y this was not working is because I took the item to look for from another list.