# I need help understanding bool = false and the meaning of -1

Tags: c#

Programming newbie here.

I have a requirement in this project that checks for duplicate player numbers entered (like Michael Jordan 23). Cannot have Dave Brown 23 because Michael already has that number assigned.

I need help understanding what is happening in this code.

Here is what I have below. I commented out with what I think is happening.

```
    static int SearchNumber(int[] playerNumbers, int newPlayerNumber, int playerCount)
    {
        //3. //

        int index = 0;
        bool found = false; //found duplicate number = not true

        while (!found && index < playerCount)//while we did find a duplicate number && index < playerCount
        {
            if (playerNumbers[index] == newPlayerNumber)
            {
                found = true; // we found a duplicate number
            }
            else //we did not find a duplicate number
            {
                index++; //add onto the team
            }

        }
        if (!found) //if we did find a duplicate number
        {
            index = -1; //subtract 1 from the team. return to menu
        }
        return index;
    }
```

Here is the part I don't understand below:

[Screen shot of code with highlighted to understand what I don't understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnZVK.png)

Thanks.

Comment: -1 is a convention some programs use to specify "we didn't find an index" while guaranteeing the return value is an integer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45598679/1043380, for example

Comment: Side note: `SearchNumber` is a very poor description of what the method should do. Invest in naming methods that accurately describe what they do and you'll spend less time figure out the code.

Comment: Setting `bool found = false` is a way of saying "I'm going to assume we haven't found it, but if I do I'll set `found = true`."

Comment: @JJLe This site is only useful if you accept an answer and upvote ones you liked. Leaving question open is not helping it

Answer (score 0):

---

*Moved this information from a comment, but I don't feel the question is strong enough on its own for me to be comfortable putting my name on it.*

---

Returning `-1` is a convention some programs use to specify "we didn't find an index" while guaranteeing the return value is an integer.

For example, [`IndexOf`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45598679/1043380) will always return an integer - either the positive index when it found a match, or -1 when it didn't.

I can only speculate about *why*, but in my experience I've seen older programs and APIs use this method, while newer ones will either throw an exception or return a *nullable* integer.

Answer (score 0):

This should be correct comments to this code

```cs
static int SearchNumber(int[] playerNumbers, int newPlayerNumber, int playerCount)
{
    int index = 0; // iteration index
    bool found = false; // flag raised when player found

    while (!found && index < playerCount)//while we did find a duplicate number && index < playerCount
    {
        if (playerNumbers[index] == newPlayerNumber) // checks if currently iterated player has the searche number
        {
            found = true; // raises the flag - player found
        }
        else //we did not find a duplicate number
        {
            index++; // simply increase iterator index
        }

     }
     if (!found) //  if we did !!! NOT !!! find a duplicate number
     {
        index = -1; // SET return value to -1 to indicate nothing found
     }
     return index;
}
```

And now same method .NET-optimized

```cs
static int SearchNumber(int[] playerNumbers, int newPlayerNumber)
{
    int len = playerNumbers.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (playerNumbers[i] == newPlayerNumber)  
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```